Microwave turns off when pressing buttons too quickly
We have a microwave attached to our cabinet and sometimes when we press the start button too fast, it burns out. We have to then unplug and plug to make it work again. I know you’re not allowed to use extension cord but does this look safe as a set up? You can see the tiny burns from the outlet.
It is a touchpad. Also, it just turns off so I have to plug and unplug it again (I’m assuming it’s being burnt out).


click it to start too fast - That is odd terminology, as most countertop microwave ovens for the last few decades have had electronic touchpad controls. So the make/model # and a picture of the controls would be very helpful.

What does "clicking" mean? What does "too fast" mean? What does "burns out" mean?

Both of those outlets are broken.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   My older microwave has start/stop on the same touch button(top/bottom).  Once in a while I will hit both buttons together, causing it to start and stop.  But I just have to hit start again.

There's nothing wrong with the way you're operating the microwave.

That does not look safe for a couple reasons at least:

There are un-sheathed individual wires coming through a hole in what looks like the "backsplash" or side piece. These individual wires should be in a piece of conduit properly connected to the metal outlet box.
The outlet has burn marks. This means the outlet is old and no longer has enough spring in the contacts to grasp the plug pins firmly, making for higher resistance and power loss, leading to high heat and fire/burning.

If "it burns out" means there is a little fire or spark at the outlet, then you need a new outlet in that box. You should also get the individual wires into a conduit and proper connection to the box. (It could be possible that enough "burn" and resultant power loss is happening to drop available power to the microwave such that the computer inside cannot recover, and a full power loss cycle is needed, thus the unplug/replug fixes the problem.)
If you are in a rental situation or don't have the proper electrical DIY skills to make these fixes yourself, then you should get an electrician to fix this. Note that if you are in a rental, the landlord is responsible for arranging for the electrician, and neither you nor the landlord are allowed to make these fixes yourselves.
